# How to remove Start button from taskbar in Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

Is it possible to remove'Start button' from taskbar in server 2012 R2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Windows server 2008 R2 or 2012 R2? Please fix your post or tags.

Comment: IMHO there is no way to disable the start button.

Comment: my mistake edited the post.

Comment: Doing a quick bit of research i have not found any possible ways to do this on windows server 2008 R2 - It depends why exactly you want to remove the start button but if you just wish to remove the ability to shut down the server this [article](http://blog.willbeattie.net/2010/01/disabling-shut-down-button-on-windows.html) may provide a bit of help.

Answer (score 1):

The above aswer is correct,to remove items from the menu,locate the following configuration :

User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu & Taskbar\

Comment: I need to remove the 'StartButton' completely from the task bar, can you please explain?.

Comment: No such functionality exists by the looks of it on server 2012,id say search for a third party start menu such as classic shell if this is an option otherwise it seems you will have to restrict user access in group policies.I hope this was useful.I tried but it seems you might not get the answer you are looking for .

Comment: Don't ask for votes in your answer. If your answer is a good one it will will be voted up anyway.

Comment: From my understanding Start Button is a new addition in Server 2012 R2 and which is not available in Server 2012, so is it possible to remove this addition?.